# What command should be used to see the previous line in DOS?

Tags: dos

To compile a java code we use the command javac FileName.java on dos. If there are lots of error in the program code,last few errors are seen only on CUI..but what about the previous one....?
I means,the screen scrolls up,because of that we are unable to visit the previous line(errors)...so how can I see them? What command will be used ???

Answer (score 3):

This will pause each screen for you to read it.

```
javac FileName.java | more
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compile it and have the output written to a file with:

```
javac FileName.java >compilerResults.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the length of the screen "buffer" in the cmd.exe properties.  Click the c:\ icon in the upper left of the window and select properties.  Go to the "Layout" tab, and increase the Screen Buffer Size and Window Size to larger values.

I'd recommend using a more powerful command line tool (e.g. Cygwin) for any significant programming tasks.  If you are familiar with Unix shells, Cygwin is an invaluable tool.